# How to prevent sgmf-scripts to scratch sensitive files?

Tags: cartridge, salesforce-commerce-cloud

Right now I’m developing a SFCC Commerce Cloud website.
Referring to SFRA recommendations, I’m using the `sgmf-scripts` command to create, compile and upload custom cartridges.

The problem is, each time I create a cartridge, `sgmf-scripts` is scratching sensitive files such as `dw.json`, `package.json` or `webpack.config.js`, which is pretty annoying.

Does anyone know how to avoid this behavior?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you are open to using Visual Studio Code, you can use this together with the Prophet Debugger. The Prophet Debugger would enable you to upload your code with each change to the Sandbox and attach VS Code to Sandbox for debugging - this takes away the need to configure multiple dw.json as Prophet Debugger reads the main dw.json

Find out more about Prophet Debugger: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SqrTT.prophet